# Circular progress from 90deg to a percentage

Tags: jquery, jquery-svg

I need help in implementing Progress bar which takes percentage as input and draws an arc starting from 90deg.

[image: knob]

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/3C8JA/7/)

```
    jQuery(svg).animate({ 'to': 1 }, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(pos, fx) {
            //var offset = (pos);
            if(pos<0.25)
            {
                if(percentage>=25)
                {
                    per=90;
                    jQuery('#percentage').html(Math.round(pos*100)+" %");
                    jQuery('#perval').html(Math.round(pos*100)+"%");
                }
                else
                {
                    per=(percentage*90/25);
                    jQuery('#percentage').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+" %");
                    jQuery('#perval').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+"%");
                }
                endx=110+50*Math.cos((PIE)*per*(1-(pos*4)));
                endy=60-50*Math.sin((PIE)*per*(1-(pos*4)));
            } else if(pos<0.75)
            {
                if(percentage>=75)
                {
                    per=180;
                    jQuery('#percentage').html(Math.round(pos*100)+" %");
                    jQuery('#perval').html(Math.round(pos*100)+"%");
                }
                else
                {
                    per= ((percentage-25)*180/50);
                    jQuery('#percentage').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+" %");
                    jQuery('#perval').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+"%");
                }
                if(pos < 0.50) {
                    endx=110+50*Math.cos((PIE)*(per*(pos-0.25)*2));
                    endy=60+50*Math.sin((PIE)*(per*(pos-0.25)*2));
                } else {
                    endx=110-50*Math.cos((PIE)*(per*(pos-0.25)*2));
                    endy=60-50*Math.sin((PIE)*(per*(pos-0.25)*2));

                }
            }   else 
            {
                per= ((percentage - 75)*90/25);
                jQuery('#percentage').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+" %");
                jQuery('#perval').html(Math.round(percentage*pos)+"%");             
                endx=110-50*Math.cos((PIE)*per*(pos*4));
                endy=60+50*Math.sin((PIE)*per*(pos*4));                 
            }
            svg.setAttribute('d',current_dx+endx+","+endy);
        }
    });
```

Starting from an angle((90deg) how to get the end pionts after 180deg.

The code does not render properly after 180deg.

Comment: Maybe start from 0, and use a transformation to change the apparent starting angle?

Comment: Why you no use this plugin? http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Comment: I am trying to create a knob in svg

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io) for SVG manipulations in a easy way. Check this knob sample [link](http://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/BqpCd) created using Snap.svg.